# Create a simple number pattern in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get this number pattern

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
012345
0123456
01234567
012345670
0123456701
```

But I can't figure out how to reset the digits when I reach over 8 in my function. There is my code:

```
def afficherPatron(n):
triangle = ''

for i in range(0, n):
    triangle = triangle + (str(i))
    print(triangle)
    i+=1
```

Thanks in advance to all of you!

Comment: You don't need `i+=1`, the `for` loop increments the variable automatically.

Comment: Is 8 related to `n` or just some sort of cyclic limitation you wanted to be?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to delete it from the code! It's because I was using a while loop before;)

Comment: It is not, bigOther answered my question right!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `i` mod 8 (`i%8`) because it is cyclic 0 to 7 :

```
for i in range(0, n):
    triangle = triangle + str(i%8)
    print(triangle)
```

Comment: I'll try this, I'm pretty sure this is what I missed! Thanks a lot:D

Answer (score 0):

I Like methods...

```
def yourPattern(b,s):
    r = ""
    q = [str(k) for k in range(1,b+1)*(s/b)+range(1,b+1)[0:s%b]]
    for k in q:#    ^Iterator[^Array ^Scale^add^Array   ^Portion]
        r += k # Put string together
    return(r)

def pattern(b,l):
    r = ""
    for k in range(1,l+1):
        r+=yourPattern(b,k)+"\n"
    return(r)
print pattern(8,18)
```

o(4n)